# Treat subclass as its superclass when only a member differs by its type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a Variable class and and 3 subclasses: VariableBool, VariableLong and VariableDouble. Each subclass defines only a value member of the type of the suffix.

Now, I need to transfert objects based on these classes over WCF. I have multiple clients registering their variale to a server. Whenever a value changes on one client, it's updated in all other clients.

My question is: is there a way to do:

```
someVar.Value = anotherVar.Value;
```

regardless of the type, wihout having to check for type, e.g.:

```
VariableBool anotherVarBool = anotherVar as VariableBool;
if (anotherVarBool != null) {
  (someVar as VariableBool).Value = anotherVar.Value;
}
// check other types...
```

What am I missing? Is there a patern of some kind? Could I use reflection?
Also, I don't think I can use Generics because of the WCF (I've tried but I could make it work).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mex-generated WCF proxies, then I suspect reflection (or ComponentModel) is indeed the simplest option - something like:

```
public static void Copy<T>(T source, T destination,
    string propertyName) {
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    prop.SetValue(destination, prop.GetValue(source, null), null);
}
```

Or if you want to use it even with the variable types as the base-class:

```
public static void Copy(object source, object destination,
    string propertyName) {
    PropertyInfo sourceProp = source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    PropertyInfo destProp = destination.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    destProp.SetValue(destination, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you to put the Value member in the base class Variable.
In that case,

```
public void UpdateValue( Variable variable )
{
   if( variable != null )
      // do something with variable.Value
}
```

However, if you really want to use inheritance, you need to tell the base class what are the sub types by using KnownType attribute and its method

```
[DataContract()]
[KnownType( "GetKnownType" )]
public class Variable
{

 public object Value;

 private static Type[] GetKnownType()
 {
   // properties
   return new []{ typeof(VariableBool),
                  typeof(VariableLong), 
                  typeof(VariableDouble),};
 }
}

[DataContract()]
public class VariableBool : Variable
{
}

[DataContract()]
public class VariableLong : Variable
{
}

[DataContract()]
public class VariableDouble : Variable
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll combine your answer with the solution. The subclasses will only be used to get a typed value